# numpy array indexing: list index and np.array index give different result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to index an np.array using list and `np.array` indexes.  But they give different result.

Here is an illustration:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.arange(10)
idx = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]
x[np.array(idx)]  # returns array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
```

but straightly apply the list gives error

```
x[idx]  # raises IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I'm expecting the above returns the same result as using `np.array` index.
Any ideas why?

I am using `python 3.5` and `numpy 1.13.1`.

Comment: In numpy 1.15, the second case will emit a warning, asking you to clarify whether you meant `x[tuple(idx)]` or `x[np.array(idx)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an array it's interpreted as shape of the final array containing the indices - but if it's an list it's the indices along the "dimensions" (multi-dimensional array indices).

So the first example (with an `array`) is equivalent to:

```
[[x[0], x[1],
 [x[1], x[2]]
```

But the second example (`list`) is interpreted as:

```
[x[0, 1], x[1, 2]]
```

But `x[0, 1]` gives a `IndexError: too many indices for array` because your `x` has only one dimension.

That's because `list`s are interpreted like it was a tuple, which is identical to passing them in "separately":

```
x[[0, 1], [1, 2]]
          ^^^^^^----- indices for the second dimension
  ^^^^^^------------- indices for the first dimension
```

Comment: Lists are [only sometimes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L200) treated like tuples.

Answer (score 1):

From ***[numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)*** documentation:

> **ndarrays** can be indexed using the standard Python `x[obj]` syntax, where `x` is the array and `obj` the selection.
>
> ... 
>   Basic slicing occurs when obj is a slice object (constructed by
>   `start:stop:step` notation inside of brackets), an integer, or a tuple
>   of `slice` objects and integers. `Ellipsis` and `newaxis` objects can be
>   interspersed with these as well. In order to remain backward
>   compatible with a common usage in Numeric, basic slicing is also
>   initiated if the selection object is any non-ndarray sequence (such as
>   a `list`) containing `slice` objects, the `Ellipsis` object, or the `newaxis`
>   object, but not *for integer arrays or other embedded sequences*. ...

Comment: Neither example in the question triggers basic slicing, though. The array triggers advanced indexing, and the list triggers different advanced indexing, for reasons the docs don't adequately explain.