# numpy array indexing with lists and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

>>> type(l), l # list of scalers
(<type 'list'>, [0, 1])

>>> type(i), i # a numpy array
(<type 'numpy.ndarray'>, array([0, 1]))

>>> type(j), j # list of numpy arrays
(<type 'list'>, [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])])
```

When I do

```
>>> a[l] # Case 1, l is a list of scalers
```

I get

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

which means **indexing happened only on 0th axis**.

But when I do

```
>>> a[j] # Case 2, j is a list of numpy arrays
```

I get

```
array([1, 4])
```

which means **indexing happened along axis 0 and axis 1**.

Q1: When used for indexing, why is there a difference in treatment of list of scalers and list of numpy arrays ? (Case 1 vs Case 2). In Case 2, I was hoping to see indexing happen only along axis 0 and get

```
array( [[[1,2],
          [3,4]], 

        [[1,2],
         [3,4]]])
```

Now, when using numpy array of arrays instead

```
>>> j1 = np.array(j) # numpy array of arrays
```

The result below indicates that **indexing happened only along axis 0** (as expected)

```
>>> a[j1] Case 3, j1 is a numpy array of numpy arrays
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Q2: When used for indexing, why is there a difference in treatment of list of numpy arrays and numpy array of numpy arrays? (Case 2 vs Case 3)

Comment: For Q1, isn't the non-Numpy analog to use `k = [[0,1], [0,1]]; a[k]`?  In that case, you see the same behavior between a list of lists and a list of Numpy arrays.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that `[a[jj] for jj in j]` gives you what you're expecting in Q1.  Inputting a list of lists, whether a Numpy array or not, is basically returning one set of indices at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case1, `a[l]` is actually `a[(l,)]` which expands to `a[(l, slice(None))]`.  That is, indexing the first dimension with the list `l`, and an automatic trailing `:` slice.  Indices are passed as a tuple to the array `__getitem__`, and extra `()` may be added without confusion.

Case2, `a[j]` is treated as `a[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]]` or `a[(array(([0, 1]), array([0, 1])]`.  In other words, as a tuple of indexing objects, one per dimension.  It ends up returning `a[0,0]` and `a[1,1]`.

Case3, `a[j1]` is `a[(j1, slice(None))]`, applying the `j1` index to just the first dimension.

Case2 is a bit of any anomaly.  Your intuition is valid, but for historical reasons, this list of arrays (or list of lists) is interpreted as a tuple of arrays.

This has been discussed in other SO questions, and I think it is documented.  But off hand I can't find those references.

So it's safer to use either a tuple of indexing objects, or an array.  Indexing with a list has a potential ambiguity.

---

[numpy array indexing: list index and np.array index give different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116568/numpy-array-indexing-list-index-and-np-array-index-give-different-result)

This SO question touches on the same issue, though the clearest statement of what is happening is buried in a code link in a comment by @user2357112.

Another way of forcing the Case3 like indexing, make the 2nd dimension slice explicit, `a[j,:]`

```
In [166]: a[j]
Out[166]: array([1, 4])
In [167]: a[j,:]
Out[167]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

(I often include the trailing `:` even if it isn't needed.  It makes it clear to me, and readers, how many dimensions we are working with.)

Answer (score 0):

A1: The structure of `l` is not the same as `j`.

`l` is just one-dimension while `j` is two-dimension. If you change one of them:

```
# l = [0, 1]                                 # just one dimension!
l = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]                         # two dimensions
j = [np.array([0,1]), np.array([0, 1])]      # two dimensions
```

They have the same behave.

A2: The same, the structure of arrays in Case 2 and Case 3 are not the same.